# How to make common calls for each matched route in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I have routes like these:

```
events_print:
    pattern:  /list
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeCompanyBundle:Events:list
        activeMenu: conferences_events_list

events_edit:
    pattern:  /edit/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeCompanyBundle:Events:edit
        activeMenu: conferences_events_edit
```

And in each action in controller I got to do this:

```
$menuBuilder = $this->container->get('acme.menu_builder');
$menuBuilder->setActiveMenu($activeMenu);
```

It would be nice if I could somehow intercept the matched route and call `setActiveMenu()` in one place rather than in each action. Is there any good way for this?

UPDATE: I've simplified the example a bit, so that you are not confused with unnecessary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is a controller listener

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    acme_controller.listener:
        class: Acme\CompanyBundle\Listener\ControllerListener
        arguments: [ @acme.menu_builder ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

<kbd>**ControllerListener.php**</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CompanyBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

/**
 * Controller listener
 */
class ControllerListener
{
    protected $menuBuilder;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Object $menuBuilder A Menu Builder instance
     */
    public function __construct($menuBuilder)
    {
        $this->menuBuilder = $menuBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the active menu
     *
     * @param  FilterControllerEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();
        $request    = $event->getRequest();

        /**
         * Your logic
         */

        $this->menuBuilder->setActiveMenu($activeMenu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this is what I needed. Just posted my solution that is pretty same. But accepting yours as better arranged.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution that might be useful for others.
We can listen kernel.controller event:

```
acme.kernel_listener:
    class: Acme\Company\Bundle\EventListener\KernelListener
    arguments:
        container: "@service_container"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

And in the event listener:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $route = $this->container->get('request')->get('_route');
    if ($routeObj = $this->container->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->get($route)) {
        $defaults = $routeObj->getDefaults();
    }
    // do some common stuff
}
```

Now we can do all the common stuff in one place.